# Strange behavior with dynamics & lambda. c# .net 4

Tags: .net

I cannot figure why the compiler thinks my dto is dynamic inside a lambda expression.
It's a bug or there's a valid reason for that?

```
[TestFixture]
public class DynamicTest
{
    public class Dto
    {
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }

    public Dto ToDto(dynamic d)
    {
        return new Dto();
    }

    [Test]
    public void dto_is_typed()
    {
        // var is Dto
        var dto = ToDto(new { dummy = true });
        dto.Value = "val";

        Assert.Inconclusive("yust for intellisense test");
    }

    [Test]
    public void dto_is_dynamic_inside_an_action_with_dynamic_type()
    {
        Action<dynamic> act = o =>
            {
                // dto is dynamic
                var dto = ToDto(o);
                dto.ThisIsNotAProperty = 100;
            };


        var ex = Assert.Throws<Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException>(() =>
            {
                act(new {dummy = true});
            });

        Assert.IsTrue(ex.Message.EndsWith("does not contain a definition for 'ThisIsNotAProperty'"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question makes no sense.  Are you getting an error message?  Is your test failing?  What do you expect for it to do?  What makes you think "the compiler thinks [your] dto is dynamic?"

Comment: the test pass. i don't have a compile exception but a runtime exception

Comment: What is your runtime exception?  What code is it that throws the exception?

Comment: @DanPuzey have you seen the test? Assert.Throws<Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException>

Comment: Yes, I've seen the test, but you've not made clear what your problem is.  You said the tests pass.  Do you expect them to fail?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fact that it's in a lambda expression is somewhat irrelevant. You've effectively got:

```
dynamic o = GetValueFromSomewhere();
var dto = ToDto(o);
```

Now the type of `dto` is `dynamic`, because the expression `ToDto(o)` is a dynamic expression: you're using a dynamic value (`o`) as an argument. Even though you know there's only one method which it will ever resolve to, the language rules force the type of the invocation expression to be `dynamic`.

You can very easily change it, just by not using `var`:

```
Action<dynamic> act = o =>
{
    // dto is dynamic
    Dto dto = ToDto(o);
    dto.ThisIsNotAProperty = 100;
};
```

This will now fail to compile - which is what I assume you wanted.

Comment: "Even though you know there's only one method which it will ever resolve to, the language rules force the type of the invocation expression to be dynamic" .. that's the answer. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`dto` is dynamic because it is the return value from a method that receives a dynamic argument.
A `dynamic` argument causes overload resultion to happen at runtime, making the exact method being called unknown to the compiler.

Comment: To be picky, it's not the fact that the *parameter* is `dynamic` that makes the result dynamic - it's the fact that the *argument* is `dynamic`. If you had `var dto = ToDto(null);` then that would *not* be a dynamic invocation.

Comment: @JonSkeet: I always mix those two. I meant the argument. Fixed, thanks